# C# .net tfs workspace operations

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfs-2015

I am trying to programmatically access tfs operations, primarily concerned with viewing, creating, modifying and removing workspaces, but also doing a get on source code. My research led me to the TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient nuget packages. I coded up this example:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri(TfsUrl),
    new VssBasicCredential(UserName, Password));                

tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    
var workspaces = vcs.QueryWorkspaces(null, @"john.doe", null);
```

Which actually works fine, but my research also indicates that this is the .net 'legacy' way of doing it and i should be doing the more modern way as indicated here: [MS DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)

Unfortunately, all the examples i can find are accessing git, which i'm not using. The connection is templated out, and i can't find documentation of classes that implement the VssHttpClientBase base class. Can anyone point me to examples, or documentation that i'm missing?

Comment: I spent ages trying to work out how to port my "legacy" TFS code to the more modern way - and gave up because I simply couldn't work out how to do it with the available documentation. So I'll be quite interested to see if you find anything useful!

Comment: Wow. It appears that the package you want to use is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client, however there appears to be NO documentation for it at Microsoft. an API search for `TeamFoundationServer` returns nothing useful.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole - the Extended client allows for me to create workspaces, which is a required function for what i'm trying to do. Of course, there's some documentation, but it's very limited and only specifically scoped examples.

Comment: I wish I had a good answer for you, Jason - if there's good documentation for it, it's being well hidden!

Comment: [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb141847(v=vs.120)) provides the APIs that are required for a client application to work with the version control functionality in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. But [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package doesn't have NetStandard support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#microsoftteamfoundationserverextendedclient-package-doesnt-have-netstandard-support).

Comment: BTW, you could view now available Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet). And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops-2020#q-where-can-i-find-more-information-on-the-net-library) provides .NET samples for Azure DevOps. But it seems that nowhere provides clear documentations about [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on Azure Devops .net samples. The github repository is https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples
A starting point could be the readme of [ClientLibrary/Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples) where you can find two sln files covering code for both core 3.1 and framework 4.5.
A quick sample, related to **Tfvc** is [ClientLibrary/Samples/Tfvc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Tfvc) . It demonstrates how to:

- work with VssConection
- enumerate branches
- list changesets
- list project items